# asp.net core 2 webapi invalid characters

Tags: character-encoding, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm having an Asp.net Core 2.0 WebApi project, and trying to access a Get () method and generating a purposeful error in it for the client.
I am sending information from Http errors to the consumer client:

```
context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "Não foi encontrado.";
```

When client receives ReasonPhrase it has invalid characters where it is accented:

> "N?o foi encontrado"

the correct would be:

> "Não foi encontrado"

I imagine I would have how to configure encoding for UTF-8 but I can not figure out ways to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: Does the client's browser support UTF-8 encoding correctly? Older browsers can have not great support for UTF-8.

Comment: Yes they have support, I am using the latest versions of chrome and firefox. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")

but as far as I know it is by default utf-8, again it is what I know and I may be very wrong

Comment: I could not find this path in .net core. I was able to find up context.HttpContext.Response,
after that it does not have ContentEncoding. Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: edited !! I do not have access to dev environment but I think this should work